Gcloud SQL Postgres 13 inplace upgrade fails for collation 'en_US.UTF-8'
I'm trying to perform and inplace upgrade a Postgres 12 database in Google Cloud to version 13. However, I get the following error:
pre-upgrade check failed: [detail:"Please change the 'LC_COLLATE' value of the postgres database to 'en_US.UTF8' before attempting an upgrade: (database: postgres, datcollate: en_US.UTF-8) "]

I saw in the documentation that the collation must be en_US.UTF8 in order to upgrade:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/upgrade-major-db-version-inplace#prepare-upgrade
It seems the only difference is the - in the name, but the collation itself should be fine.
Is there a way around this? Can I fix the current collation in some way?
